# How do I create a time string from a number of seconds in APL?

Tags: time, apl

I would like to turn a number-of-seconds-since midnight into an HH:MM:SS formatted string.

For example, the number `17672` should turn into the string `'04:54:32'`. I can do the math to get the integer components, like so:

```
      T←17672
      H←⌊T÷3600
      MS←3600|T
      M←⌊MS÷60
      S←60|T
      H M S
4 54 32
```

But I do not know how to join the three components of this array into a string (separated by colons), *and* left pad each time component with a zero. For example, I would want

```
6 0 8
```

to be `'06:00:08'`.

I can use either GNU APL or the online [ngn-apl](https://ngn.github.io/apl/web/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to improve the calculation by using the "[encode](http://help.dyalog.com/15.0/Content/Language/Primitive%20Functions/Encode.htm)"-function:

```
      24 60 60⊤17672
4 54 32
```

To format these numbers and insert the colon, I typically use `⎕FMT` which is a vendor-specific function to format numbers as strings. A general way to do this in most APLs might be this:

```
     a←,⍕3 1⍴24 60 60⊤17672
     1↓,':',3 2⍴('0',a)[1+(⍳⍴a)×a≠' ']
04:54:32
```

Finally, instead of executing this in the session, you could put it into a function:

```
R←FormatSecs secs;a
a←,⍕3 1⍴60 60 60⊤secs
R←1↓,':',3 2⍴('0',a)[1+(⍳⍴a)×a≠' ']
```

Let's test it:

```
 FormatSecs 17672
04:54:32
```

Task accomplished ;-)

Comment: Great stuff here! I did indeed desire a function, which I produced here https://ngn.github.io/apl/web/#code=%0Atime%20%u2190%20%7B%0A%20%20H%20%u2190%20%u230A%20%u2375%20%F7%203600%20%0A%20%20MS%20%u2190%203600%20%7C%20%u2375%20%0A%20%20M%20%u2190%20%u230A%20MS%20%F7%2060%20%0A%20%20S%20%u2190%2060%20%7C%20%u2375%20%0A%20%20H%2C%27%3A%27%2CM%2C%27%3A%27%2CS%0A%7D%0A%0Atime%2011%201%20%u2374%20%u230A%28%28%u2373%2011%29%20+%200.5%29%20%D7%2043200.0%20%F7%2011%0A but unfortunately got spaces between my colons. `encode` is awesome.

Comment: Actually, the reason you had these blanks in your results is that you left the numbers as numbers and produced a heterogenous result - then APL inserts blanks as separators. You could improve that code by doing `H ←¯2↑'0',⍕ ⌊ ⍵ ÷ 3600`etc.

Comment: Alternatively, R ← 1 ↓ , ':' , 0 1↓⍕(0 60 60 ⊤ X)∘.+,100

Answer (score 3):

In extended APL (all modern APLs) you can use

```
1↓∊':',¨¯2↑¨⍕¨100+24 60 60⊤T
```

ngn/apl has a non-conforming `⍕` so you'll need

```
1↓∊':',¨¯2↑¨,¨⍕¨100+24 60 60⊤T
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.github.io/apl/web/#code=1%u2193%u220A%27%3A%27%2C%A8%AF2%u2191%A8%2C%A8%u2355%A8100+24%2060%2060%u22A417672)

You in Dyalog, GNU and ngn/apl you can make a dfn (lambda) out of it by enclosing it in braces. Try it [in ngn/apl](https://ngn.github.io/apl/web/#code=T%u219017672%0Af%u2190%7B1%u2193%u220A%27%3A%27%2C%A8%AF2%u2191%A8%2C%A8%u2355%A8100+24%2060%2060%u22A4%u2375%7D%0Af%20T) and [in Dyalog APL](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@RR2wRDczNzI640IKva8FHb5EcdXepW6jqHVhxab/SobeKhFY96px5aYWhgoG1komBmAESPupY86t1a@/9/mkIIAA).

Using Dyalog APL version 16.0 or higher, you can use the `@` operator to place colons:

```
{1↓':'@4 7∊⍕¨100+24 60 60⊤⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@RR2wRDczNzI640IKva8FHbZHUrdQcTBfNHHV2PeqceWmFoYKBtZKJgZgBEj7qWPOrdWvv/f5pCCAA)